# Unable to connect to remote server with vnc viewer

Tags: server, remote-desktop, vnc, tightvncserver, vncviewer

(Tight)VNC server at the remote desktop is set up well. This I could verify by connecting to it from my PC (Ubuntu 18.04). But when I try to login to the server from my laptop (Ubuntu 16:04) using Real VNC (client), I get an error message which says:
`Unable to connect via my_ip:port: VNC viewer was unable to negotiate a connection with the proxy due to a protocol error`

Can anyone help?

Update: I am able to access the remote server using Remmina remote desktop client. The problem with Real VNC still persists.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Which VNC server? Which VNC client? Please edit and update your question.

Comment: @user68186 Done. I have many different versions of VNC in my laptop. However, Real VNC is run as default when I write "vncviewer" on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I use RealVNC to connected the remote windows, I also found the issue today, but after I change the `Properties -> Expert -> Filter:proxy -> ProxyTcpRfb, set value = false`, It works again.

[image]